# Adding a calculation to the title of a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtitle

I'm new to R and wondering if the following is possible to calculation in the title of a ggplot scatter.  The code below is how I thought it might be possible.

```
AlexPlot + ggtitle("Alex's BG, The average is " + mean(Alex$bg, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Try `ggtitle(paste0("Alex's BG, The average is ", paste0(mean(Alex$bg, na.rm = TRUE))))`

Comment: Thank you but recived error "Error in +ggtitle(paste0("Alex's BG, The average is ", paste0(mean(Alex$bg,  : 
  invalid argument to unary operator"

Comment: Please post the rest of your code or something that is reproducible. That error is likely due to something else. ie. you may have too many `+`  or are using them in the wrong place

Comment: sorry I must have miss-typed tried again and it worked thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't shared your data, I am using `mpg` dataset; you need to wrap the text and the numeric calculation within `paste` function. The comment above works as well, but I am not sure why we need to use `paste0` twice!

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg) + 
  geom_point(aes(hwy, displ)) +
  ggtitle(paste("Average mpg is", round(mean(mpg$hwy, na.rm = TRUE),2)))
```

[image]

As you can see, this works. You need to share a reproducible example of your data, if you get an error related to your specific data.